# Load a Div from Menu click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the below code to load a page in my main div when a user clicks on a nav menu item (top horizontal):

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#pia").click(function(){
        $("#main").load("pia.htm");
    }); 
});
</script>
```

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SomeProducts">
 <div class="myContainer">
   <div class="menuIframe">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#"><b>Products</b> <img src="down_arrow.jpg"/></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a id="pia" href="#">Panel Instruments & Accessories</a></li>             
                            <li><a id="stc" href="#">Sequence Timers & Controllers</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
          </div>
       <div id ="main" class="mainIframe">
       <img src="13.jpg"/>
       </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

However, the page loading is not working when I click on the menu item. Wondering what am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does the console give any errors ? is pia.htm in the same directory ? And like the answer below you want to prevent default so the link isn't followed.

Comment: There is cross-domain error in your code. Please check in console and verify that ..

Answer (score 0):

Add preventDefault:

```
$("#pia").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#main").load("pia.htm");
});
```

This will stop the normal behaviour of the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways :

1. make 'href attribute' `javascript:;`. `<a href="javascript:;">`.
2. using event.preventDefault(); on click function

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#pia").on('click', function(e){
            $("#main").load("pia.htm");
        }); 
});
</script>
```

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SomeProducts">
 <div class="myContainer">
   <div class="menuIframe">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="javascript:;"><b>Products</b> <img src="down_arrow.jpg"/></a>
                        <ul>
                            <!-- make href attribute value javascript:; -->
                            <li><a id="pia" href="javascript:;">Panel Instruments & Accessories</a></li>             
                            <li><a id="stc" href="javascript:;">Sequence Timers & Controllers</a></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
          </div>
       <div id ="main" class="mainIframe">
       <img src="13.jpg"/>
       </div>
     </div>
</body>
```